# HTTPS/PKI Server Public / Private keypair

Tags: https, pki

In the HTTPS secure session handshake, I understand that the server presents its public key, and that the client encrypts a symmetric session key with the public key and returns it to the server.

My question, is when does the server generate its private/public key pair?  I could see it generating it for each connection, and I could see it having a single one that it reuses for every connection.  It would seem more secure to create the key pair for every connection.  Does it matter?

Comment: One aspect is the time needed to generate a good key. Generating a good key needs some time, so it's not fully done on every connection.

Comment: Depends on the algorithm – keys for RSA take a long time to generate, keys for traditional DH are relatively fast _if_ the base parameters have been pre-generated, and keys for some elliptic-curve algorithms are practically instant (just take bits straight out of a CSPRNG). The latter is what makes ECDHE so popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, TLS has **[several](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/what-key-exchange-mechanism-should-be-used-in-tls)** key exchange types. The method you're describing has actually been phased out a while ago – nearly all TLS connections in practice generate the symmetric key using Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm instead.

In the older so-called "static RSA key exchange" protocol that you describe, the server didn't generate key pairs at all; it always used the pre-existing key pair *from its TLS certificate.* (Usually the certificate's keypair is generated by the sysadmin.)

The server would present its X.509 certificate (which includes the public key); the client would verify it, then use its public key to encrypt the shared secret. If the server was able to decrypt it, that would additionally act as a proof for clients that the server actually owns the presented certificate.

But this method has been phased out, partly because of [issues with RSA encryption](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/bleichenbachers-cat-rsa-key-exchange/) (as opposed to RSA signing), partly because it did not offer "forward secrecy" as all symmetric secrets were encrypted with the same permanent key.

Sumilarly, TLS has two kinds of Diffie-Hellman key exchange; "static DH" where the server always uses the same DH parameters from its certificate (which as you can guess has problems similar to static RSA) and "ephemeral DH" where the DH keypairs are regenerated for every connection.

> It would seem more secure to create the key pair for every connection. Does it matter?

It would indeed be more secure if the server could generate generate temporary keypairs and sign them with its "main" key as proof.

For RSA key exchange, this method has never been used in SSL or TLS, although it *has* been used in SSHv1 (which has also been completely phased out very long ago). In SSHv1, the server daemon used to generate a temporary RSA keypair on startup and then every hour or so.

But for "ephemeral DH" i.e. (EC)DHE key exchange, this is exactly what is being done. The server generates a new DH keypair *for each connection* and uses its certificate to sign it.

**So the short answer is:**

- With `RSA`, `DH`, `ECDH` ciphersuites the server's keypair is static and the public key is embedded into its TLS certificate (therefore regenerated only when the sysadmin gets a new certificate).
- With `DHE` and `ECDHE` ciphersuites the server's keypair is generated for every connection.

Comment: Thanks   So, if I were using stunnel with a configuration option of say, ciphers=DHE_RSA_AES256_SHA it would use ephemeral keys for each connection and use an AES for the symetric keys.  If so, you've been a lot of help and I thank you much.

Comment: And it's also probably worth noting.  The reason I did not find any reference to this in stunnel, apache, or ssl discussions is that it's a cipher algorithm, not something to do with the apps or ssl framework.  This is an important distinction.

Comment: Well, the general mechanics are not TLS-specific (things like DH and AES can obviously be found in many protocols), but the _specific_ algorithm collections (also called "cipher suites", like the DHE_RSA_ AES256_SHA you mentioned) and the exact means of using them are defined as part of the TLS standard and so they're very much related to SSL/TLS. For example, TLSv1.2 adds support for GCM-based symmetric ciphers.